# How to update a list of dicts in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary, pymongo

I have some records like that in collection:

```
{ 
    '_id': 1,
    'test_field': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
}
```

test_field is a list of dicts. I need to push new dict in that list if any key does not exist and if it does I need to update that key’s value.

**Examples:**

1. `{'key1': 'test_value'}` → `'test_field': [{'key1': 'test_value'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]`
2. `{'test_key': 'test_value2'}` → `'test_field': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}, {'test_key': 'test_value_2'}]`

Help please

Comment: You can use the update operation - `$push`. You can check for the existence of the list element in the update's _filter_. Or,you can just do a `$addToSet` and this will add the list element only if t doesn't exist.

Comment: I know about it. But I need to push new dict in list only if key does not exist. If key exists I need to **update** it's value.

Comment: Then you can use Update with Aggregation Pipeline (this is a feature of MongoDB v4.2 or later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need a function in python to do it, this might work for you.

```
def modify_test_field(my_dict, test_field, new_key, new_val):
    my_dict[test_field] = [obj for obj in my_dict[test_field] if new_key not in obj]
    my_dict[test_field].append({new_key: new_val})
```

and call it like `modify_test_field(orig_dict, 'test_field', new_key, new_val)`